# React Transition Group Lifecycle event not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-transition-group

I'm having some trouble with transitions on my project.

So i have a transition like fade between pageloads of a new route.

Just like this:

```
         <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                        transitionName="page-swap"
                        className="page-animation"
                        component="div"
                        //transitionAppear
                        transitionEnter={this.props.loading}
                        transitionEnterTimeout={1000}
                        transitionAppearTimeout={1000}
                        transitionLeaveTimeout={1000}>
                        {!this.props.loading &&
                            React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { key: location.pathname, props: this.props })
                        }
                        {this.props.loading &&
                            <div key="loading-state">
                                <Loading />
                            </div>
                        }
                    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

Since I need to load informations before loading a component i use the same loading component while im fetching info from the server just like this:

```
 if (!terms || terms.isFetching) {
        return (
            <Loading />
        );
    }

    if (terms.error !== undefined) {
        return (
            <div>Error</div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div className="support-page text">
            info rendered.....
        </div>
    );
```

So my trouble is that when the transition is executing my component renders and display another loading component.

So I've been looking over the internet and found out that i can use a Low level API to get lifecycle events on the transition. So if i could use that lifecycle i would know if my transition as ended or not. So I've used this:

```
import TransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group/TransitionGroup'; 

 ......
<TransitionGroup
                        className="page-animation"
                        component="div"
                    >
                        {!this.props.loading &&
                            React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { key: location.pathname, props: this.props })
                        }
                        {this.props.loading &&
                            <div key="loading-state">
                                <Loading />
                            </div>
                        }
                    </TransitionGroup>
```

and on the children component called the life cycle events

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {

componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchTermsIfNeeded();
}

componentWillEnter(callback) {
    callback();
    console.log('componentWillEnter');
}

componentDidEnter() {
    console.log('componentDidEnter');
}

componentWillLeave(callback) {
    callback();
    console.log('componentWillLeave');
}

componentDidLeave() {
    console.log('componentDidLeave');
}

render() {
    const terms = this.props.support.terms;
    const DOMPurify = createDOMPurify(typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : fakeWindow);

    if (!terms || terms.isFetching) {
        return (
            <Loading />
        );
    }
    if (terms.error !== undefined) {
    return (
        <div>Error</div>
    );
}

return (
    <div className="support-page text">
        info rendered.....
    </div>
);
}
}
```

So I was expecting some console.log info but i dont seem to be triggering any of the lifecycle events of this low level API.

All tis information is based on this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Lhtoxsds/ but i still cant execute the lifecycle events

Can somebody help?